# Required additional row in select on the basis of some condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with columns : attribute_1,attribute_2,org_name,country

```
attribute_1  attribute_2  org_name  country
wcc_4599        null        org1     IN
wcc_0123        wcc_1983    org2     IN
wcc_2390        null        org3     US
wcc_5647        wcc_8789    org4     IN
```

My requirements are :

1. On the basis of following conditions i have to decide the document_type

   ```
        (i) if country  = India , attribute_1 != null, attribute_2  = null THEN Document Type ==> PAN
       (ii) if country  = India , attribute_1 != null, attribute_2 != null THEN Document Type ==> PAN , PROPRIETORSHIP DOCUMNENT
      (iii) if country != India , attribute_1 != null, attribute_2  = null THEN Document Type ==> COMPANY REGISTRAION DOCUMENT
   ```
2. for case (ii) i need to show two rows for each record, first for attribute_1 and second for attribute_2

I have following query

```
SELECT   
     attribute_1,
     attribute_2,
     upper(org_name) org_name,                      
     country,
CASE
    WHEN country = 'IN'
         AND attribute_1 IS NOT NULL
         AND attribute_2 IS NULL THEN 'PAN'
    WHEN country = 'IN'
         AND attribute_1 IS NOT NULL
         AND attribute_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'PAN , PROPRIETORSHIP DOCUMNENT'
    WHEN country != 'IN'
         AND attribute_1 IS NOT NULL
         AND attribute_2 IS NULL THEN 'COMPANY REGISTRAION DOCUMENT'     
END
doc_name
            FROM
                tbl_1
            ORDER BY
                created_date_time;
```

OUTPUT :

```
attribute_1  attribute_2  org_name  country doc_type
wcc_4599        null        org1     IN      PAN
wcc_0123        wcc_1983    org2     IN      PAN, PROPRIETORSHIP DOCUMENT
wcc_2390        null        org3     US      COMPANY REGISTRAION DOCUMENT
wcc_5647        wcc_8789    org4     IN      PAN, PROPRIETORSHIP DOCUMENT
```

But i need output like :

```
attribute_1_2  org_name country doc_type
wcc_4599        org1     IN      PAN
wcc_0123        org2     IN      PAN
wcc_1983        org2     IN      PROPRIETORSHIP DOCUMENT
wcc_2390        org3     US      COMPANY REGISTRAION DOCUMENT
wcc_5647        org4     IN      PAN
wcc_8789        org4     IN      PROPRIETORSHIP DOCUMENT
```

For the time being i have created a procedure to get the required output. But I want to do this by query. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nvl2` to mark row as 1-row of 2-row type. Then use `unpivot` which will produce needed rows while removing nulls. Last step is to assign proper `doc_type`s according to business logic:

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e4a499aadab99d58a385a44cb26fcd02)</sup>**

```
select attr, upper(org_name) org, country, 
       case when (rws = 1 and country = 'IN') or (rws = 2 and val = 'A1') then 'PAN'
            when rws = 1 then 'COMPANY REGISTRATION DOCUMENT' 
            else 'PROPRIETORSHIP DOCUMENT'
       end doc_type
  from (
    select * 
      from (select tbl_1.*, nvl2(attribute_2, 2, 1) rws from tbl_1) t
      unpivot (attr for val in (attribute_1 as 'A1', attribute_2 as 'A2')))
```

Result:

```
ATTR     ORG  COUNTRY DOC_TYPE
-------- ---- ------- -----------------------------
wcc_4599 ORG1 IN      PAN
wcc_0123 ORG2 IN      PAN
wcc_1983 ORG2 IN      PROPRIETORSHIP DOCUMENT
wcc_2390 ORG3 US      COMPANY REGISTRATION DOCUMENT
wcc_5647 ORG4 US      PAN
wcc_8789 ORG4 US      PROPRIETORSHIP DOCUMENT
6 rows selected
```

`unpivot` is available in Oracle 11g or later. In older versions you can do it using `union all` or by joining mapping table.

**Edit:** `union all` query, which may be more readable:

```
select attribute_1 attr, upper(org_name) org, country,
       case when country = 'IN' or attribute_2 is not null then 'PAN'
            else 'COMPANY REGISTRATION DOCUMENT'
       end doc_type
  from tbl_1
union all
select attribute_2 attr, upper(org_name) org, country, 'PROPRIETORSHIP DOCUMENT'
  from tbl_1
  where attribute_2 is not null
```

Comment: Both the solutions have fulfilled my need. I'll study pivot/unpivot. After breaking your query in parts, I have understood now what is happening. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a missing table here, one which could map the scalar output of the `CASE` expression to one or more rows.  Consider using the following CTE, and also place your current query into a CTE:

```
WITH doc_type AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'PAN' AS type FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'PAN' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'PROPRIETORSHIP DOCUMNENT' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'COMPANY REGISTRAION DOCUMENT' FROM dual
),
cte AS (
    SELECT
        attribute_1,
        attribute_2,
        UPPER(org_name) org_name,
        country,
        created_date_time
    CASE WHEN country = 'IN' AND
              attribute_1 IS NOT NULL AND
              attribute_2 IS NULL THEN 1
         WHEN country = 'IN' AND
              attribute_1 IS NOT NULL AND
              attribute_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 2
         WHEN country != 'IN' AND
              attribute_1 IS NOT NULL AND
              attribute_2 IS NULL THEN 3 END AS doc_id
    FROM tbl_1
)
```

Now we can join your current computed column from the `CASE` expression to generate the records you expect:

```
SELECT
    t1.attribute_1,
    t1.attribute_2,
    t1.org_name,
    t1.country,
    t2.type
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN doc_type t2
    ON t1.doc_id = t2.id
ORDER BY
    t1.created_date_time;
```